# Resources to learn probability with mathematica?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, reference-request

Can someone recommend me any resources to learn Probability with Mathematica. Hopefully a book that has mathematica exercises and code examples.

Comment: There are none worth coughing up $$ for, IMO (that is, *Mathematica* oriented). 
"Introduction to Probability with Mathematica" by Hastings is the closest fit, pretty poorly written.
You can get the old version of "Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica" by Rose et al. for free online. Mediocre writing, and really targeted at users of the non-free *Mathstatica* add-on package.

You'll be far better off getting a decent probability book other than these, and use *Mathematica* to work through examples/exercises. As a bonus, you'll improve your Mathematica skills along the way.

Comment: Although I generally agree with almost everything @ciao says, the absolute best mathematical statistics book and Mathematica-related software (which includes probability techniques) is found at http://www.mathstatica.com/:  Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica by Colin Rose and Murray Smith.  And it depends what one means by "old":  the latest version is dated 2013 (with the original version in 2002).

Comment: I have Hastings book, terribly written and also dependent on his add-ons.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you are not going to learn prob/stat via any programming language. It's simply putting the cart before the horse. I recommend you focus on a good, well-seasoned freshman textbook, perhaps one used for the Stat 101 course required of nursing students - because the examples tend to be good. Once you're an ace at that, move on up to a text used for the junior level course required of mathematics majors. I also recommend that while engaged in these studies, you swing over to the Wolfram U pages where you'll find self-paced courses to assist implementing what you're learning from the texts. https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/

- Old professors never die, they just lose their faculties.